# How to change font color of a textView

Tags: android, fonts

I want to use the below method of textView to change the font color. 
What format can I use to specify the color?

`public void setTextColor (int color)`

Sets the text color for all the states (normal, selected, focused) to be this color.

I've tried this:
`text.setTextColor(#FF0000)`

But it's not a valid syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TextView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

TextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Or this :

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0)); // rgb( red , green , blue ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

For set that color u have many options...
1  textview.setTextColor(Color.rgb(012,255,0));

2 first define the color in values...
  values.xml is define in your project under src folder...
  U can add your color as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World</string>
    <string name="app_name">XYZ</string>
    <color name="SkyBlue">#56A5EC</color>
    <color name="Green">#347C17</color>
  </resources>
```

after define color in values simply use as below...

textview.setTextColor(R.Color.SkyBlue);

Answer (score 2):

It expects a 32bit color value. You can create one using the Color class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb(int, int, int)

edit: you can also use 0xAARRGGBB (in your case, that would be 0x00FF0000 for pure red).

Answer (score 2):

You should use the color class. Read about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Answer (score 1):

I am totally agree with answers of Mohit Kanada and Houcine.

But let me add something here, you can also use some **built-in resources provided by android** itself, just refer below image:
[image]